# object to camera transformation c++

Tags: c++, coordinates, transformation

What is the best way to calculate a camera position, if I know the coordinates of an object in relation to it?

eg:

An object in the camera view has coordinates of:
position xyz = 20,30,40
rotation xyz = 3,4,5

These coordinates are in relation to the camera sensor, so the camera coordinates are:
position xyz = 0,0,0
rotation xyz = 0,0,0

if we flip that and consider the object's centre to be the zero point, where is the camera?

I have found some answers for doing this in openGL, with a transform matrix, but I am looking to do it in pure c++, from the 6 coordinates above. Is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: Isn't it just the inverse of each component individually?

Comment: I would do some reading on Direction Cosine Matrix's (DCM): http://www.starlino.com/dcm_tutorial.html

Comment: If so I have been hugely over thinking it. More than likely.  I will read up some more. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian yes, but it's also the inverse order in which the translation and the rotation is applied! If the object (at origin in world coordinates) is first translated then rotated into camera space, the camera has first to be inversly rotated then inversly translated to get into world space. there is even more to it, If the object has a generic world transformation (rotation and translation) and you have its transform in camera space. Then you need to reverse both transforms in reverse order.

Comment: The object will be static, the camera moving. I will most likely call the object center the world origin, for simplicity. So i can just invert the translation, followed by the rotation, is that right?

Thanks all!